# How do I use a quote that was basically made up?

Tags: grammaticality, quotations, mla

I know the title sounds a bit ridiculous, but that's actually what I'm asking. The sentence in question is as follows:

> "Well, of course robots don't deserve rights, they're not even living things!", may be a common response to the problem dealing with future robotic ethics.

I don't know if I'm correct in using it like that, but I would like some feedback on if this is right, and if not, what should I do?

By the way, I'm using MLA format and I couldn't find anything useful on the internet about this situation. Honestly, I don't know what to call this type of quote so I had a hard time looking it up in the first place.

Comment: As "" is not used only for quotes, so I think using "" is a fine punctuation in your sentence anyway.

Comment: According to my logic in my answer on the duplicate question, your quote is quoting some hypothetical people who are in the future.